# Django rest serializer nested objects serialized as OrderedDict instead of pure JSON

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization

How to make Django serializer to serialize nested objects as json instead of ordereddict?

```
class SummaryGroupContract:
    class Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
        total = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)

    def __init__(self, total: Decimal):
        self.total = total

class SummaryResponse:
    class Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
        income = SummaryGroupContract.Serializer(required=False)
        expenses = SummaryGroupContract.Serializer(required=False)

    def __init__(self, income: SummaryGroupContract, expenses: SummaryGroupContract):
        self.income = income;
        self.expenses = expenses;

class SummaryViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        income = SummaryGroupContract(10.0)
        expenses = SummaryGroupContract(-90.0)

        return Response(SummaryResponse.Serializer(SummaryResponse(income, expenses)).data)
```

returns

```
{'income': OrderedDict([('total', '10.00')]), 'expenses': OrderedDict([('total', '-90.00')])}
```

expected

```
{'income': {'total': '10.00'}, 'expenses': {'total': '-90.00'}}
```

EDIT: !!!!
I have resolved my issue and now everything works fine. Problem was that in my test I was inspecting response.data, which is not fully rendered response

```
response = self.client.get("/api/summary", format="json")
print(response.data)
```

instead I switched to response.content and now I get proper json (I also mistaken python object with json response).

Comment: This is what happens when you over complicate code with nested classes. This is a Python issue

Comment: And this really isn't how you use DRF serialisers.